# Assigning fraction input a/b / c/d to x = a/b, y = c/d sign= /. Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

How to make the program check for the sign if it was /,*,-,+ and split it.
the problem also comes when the sign is /. how can I tell the program to only split the / in the middle and not the actual fraction?

```
askfraction = input("Enter a fraction arithmetic operation: ")
askfraction = askfraction.replace(" ", "")
temp = askfraction.split("+")
listToStr = ' '.join(map(str, temp)) 
temp1 = listToStr.split("/")
listToStr2 = ' '.join(map(str, temp1))
temp2 = listToStr2.split(' ')
a,b,c,d = temp2
sign = "+"
x = a+"/"+b
y = c+"/"+d
print("x: "+ x +"sign: " + sign + "y: "+y)
```

test input:

```
3/4 + 1/2
```

test output:

```
x: 3/4, sign: +, y: 1/2
```

i would like to hopefully make this program detect any sign such as +,/,*,- and split accordingly. I just don't know how the program can know a fraction from a operator sign.
Expected input:

```
3/4 / 1/2
```

Expected output:

```
x: 3/4, sign: /, y: 1/2
```

thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you include an input and its expected output as well?

Comment: done sir, i hope that according to the input, the sign would change. i tried for the past few days but no luck.

Comment: Are you sure you want to do this? Under the usual rules of associativity , `3/4/1/2` does *not* parse as `(3/4)/(1/2)` but instead parses as `(3/4)/1)/2`

Comment: yes, i want the outcome to be (3/4) / (1/2). is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a regular expression to pick out the various numbers and sign. It's easier if the expected input is fixed in format, that is we're expecting fractions and an operator sign with or without spaces on either side of it.

Try this:

```
import re

REGEX_FRACTION = r'(\d+)\/(\d+) ?([+-/\*]) ?(\d+)\/(\d+)'

test_input = '3/4 + 1/2'

matchObj = re.match(REGEX_FRACTION, test_input)
if matchObj:
    fraction_1_numerator = int(matchObj.group(1))
    fraction_1_denominator = int(matchObj.group(2))
    sign = matchObj.group(3)
    fraction_2_numerator = int(matchObj.group(4))
    fraction_2_denominator = int(matchObj.group(5))

    print("fraction 1: %d/%d, sign: %s, fraction 2: %d/%d"%(fraction_1_numerator, fraction_1_denominator, sign, fraction_2_numerator, fraction_2_denominator))

    #calculate
    fraction_1 = fraction_1_numerator/fraction_1_denominator
    fraction_2 = fraction_2_numerator/fraction_2_denominator

    if sign == '+':
        print(fraction_1+fraction_2)
    elif sign == '-':
        print(fraction_1-fraction_2)
    elif sign == '*':
        print(fraction_1*fraction_2)
    elif sign == '/':
        print(fraction_1/fraction_2)
```

Comment: great, works perfectly. im wondering i it is possible to do the same if the input didn't have spaces before and after the sign.

Comment: oh, Nvm, great it works find now just had to delete the spaces in REGEN. great answer!

Comment: I changed the REGEX and just added a `?` after each space in it to make the space optional.

Comment: oh wow, didn't know you can do that. i guess now i know what will be my next thing to learn. this REGEX looks pretty handy. thanks a lot!

Comment: may i know what to search for to learn more about this?

Comment: Regular Expression: https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html#regex-howto